# Topology of set-theoretic limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

The convergence of a sequence of subsets of a fixed set $\Omega$ is defined in-terms of [set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) which does not use any metric or topology on $2^{\Omega}.$ Now I wonder:

> What is the smallest topology on $2^{\Omega}$ that induces by these convergent sequences?

For a finite set $\Omega$ this seems to be the discrete (or co-finite) topology. But for infinite sets I have no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We naturally have $2^\Omega = \prod_{\omega \in \Omega} \{0,1\}$ with the product topology, where the topology on $\{0,1\}$ (which corresponds to a singleton of $\Omega$) must be the discrete topology.

Coincidentally, using this natural identification and $f \in \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}\{0,1\} \iff f : \Omega \to \{0,1\},$ then the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of any such sequence of sets become their standard definitions when identified as functions.

---

Here are some details:

- The natural correspondence of sets (in fact, of lattices) is $$A \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \iff \mathbf{1}_A \in \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}\{0,1\}, \\ \text{where } \mathbf{1}_A(\omega) = \begin{cases}1, & \omega \in A \\ 0, & \omega \not\in A\end{cases}$$
- Under this correspondence, given any sequence $(A_n)$ of subsets of $\Omega,$ we can set $$L = \liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq 1} \bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k \\ U = \limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$$ and show that $$\mathbf{1}_L = \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_n} \\ \mathbf{1}_U = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_n}$$ where the limits infimum and supremum on the right side is defined by the standard pointwise definition for functions $f : \Omega \to \{0,1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ **[Show this.]**
- From the previous step, we see that $\{0,1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ must be assigned its subspace topology, which is the discrete topology.  Also, since the liminf and limsup in the function space are defined pointwise, convergence in $\prod_{\omega\in \Omega} \{0,1\}$ can be recognized as pointwise convergence, which means it has the product topology. **[Depending on your definition of product topology, this might need to be shown, but it's straight-forward]**

Comment: This does require some proof though. It's not completely obvious.

Comment: As @HennoBrandsma, pointed out, this is not completely obvious for me. Also how do we know that this is the smallet such topolgy?

Comment: @Bumblebee While I can agree it's not obvious, the proof is effectively just writing down the definitions, moving everything into the function space to recognize limsup and liminf as their standard pointwise definitions, and noting that the product topology is defined as the smallest topology in which the projections are continuous (i.e. in which convergence is equivalent to pointwise convergence)

Comment: @Bumblebee I've added some details to elaborate on what my argument is.  If you still have a question, it should help to at least specify in which step your concern lies.